# Directory navigation in command prompts

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file that exists in one folder, from a batch file in another folder:

Parent folder Big containes 2 folders BatchFolder and Medium.
BatchFolder contains a batch file called Batch1.
Medium contains another folder called Small.
Small contains a batch file called Batch2 that needs to run Batch1.
The command prompt is run from the location of Batch2

Therefor, how do I navigate up the folders To Big, and then navigate into the BatchFolder?

I've been trying alsorts to achieve this with no success, such as Bacth2 containing the following "call ../BatchFolder/Batch1.bat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you really need to navigate to the required folder (i.e. set it as the current one) or you simply need a way to call the batch script in that folder using a *relative path* notation. *Navigating*, from how I understand the term, means the former, but your last sentence seem to show that you need the latter.

First, the answer:

```
call %~dp0%..\..\BatchFolder\Batch1.bat
```

Next, what it means. `%~dp0%` is a variation of `%0`: the latter is the full path to this batch file (i.e. `Batch2.bat`) including the file name, and the former is the full path to this batch's folder (including the trailing `\`).

`..` points to the immediate parent folder. It is repeated twice because we need to access the 'grand-parent' of the `Batch2.bat`'s folder, and the grand-parent is `Big`. Once we are pointing to `Big`, we can address the files/folders in it, in this case it's `BatchFolder` that we need, and eventually we can put the name of `Batch1.bat`.

This works regardless of what the *current folder* is. That is, in case I wasn't clear on that head, by simply calling a batch file you are not yet changing the current folder. You would have to use the `CD` command for that. That would be *navigating* (but I'm still open to being corrected as to my understanding of this term).