# Java: relative path for data file

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I have developed a GUI application in NetBeans (v. 7.2.1) on Mac (OS version 10.6.8). This application requires an XML file (containing data used by the program), which I would like to place in a subdirectory `data`.

The trouble is that if I want to run my application from within NetBeans, this data directory has to be placed inside the main project directory; however, if I want to simply run the `.jar` file (using a doubleclick), located in the `dist` subdir of the main dir, I have to move the data folder into `dist` - and then the program will no longer run from within NetBeans.

This is how the data file path is specified within the program:

```
public String vocabPath = "data" + File.separator + "wordlist.xml";
public File vocabFile = new File(vocabPath);
```

In itself at first this did not seem problematic, as, for redistribution of the application, I thought I could simply move the data directory into `dist`, and distribute that (which worked fine on OS X and Windows 7); however, on Ubuntu I got an error message saying the data file was not found.

I am new to Java, so perhaps this is a daft question, but anyway: how can I get my application to always access the data file located in `MAIN_DIR/dist/data`? Or if the root of the problem lies somewhere else, then please let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**

I have posted a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13502828/475845), as I think I have narrowed down the problem to some unexpected behaviour which only occurs under Ubuntu.

**EDIT 2**

An answer to my follow-up question (see first edit) has solved my problem (just as a note to those who've found this post while trying to solve a problem similar to mine).

Comment: How did it really work on windows and OS X? How do you run the application?

Comment: @Jayan I ran the application by double-clicking on the .jar file. It worked perfectly on OS X and Windows.

Comment: Okay, so the process got launched with 'current working' directory to the location of jar, hence the File got the path correct.  How are you running in on linux?

Comment: @jayan I was running it in the very same way - by double-clicking on the .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

If the file `wordlist.xml` is not modifiable by user, you could include it as part of jar and use `getResourceAsStream()` to load it. Some additional details are here at [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

if the data is expected to be modified , you may keep it at some known location. [Users home directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) is available via `user.home` property. (and is probably a good area)

Having a file relative to 'installation' (MAIN_DIR) is more difficult if it is a pure java program started by java command.  You may create an executable and the use some operating system api (`readlink ("/proc/self/exe", ..)` on Linux) to resolve the installation location.

Packaging java program with native executable could be done by software like [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html).

(Launch4J is an opensource solution with similar features, could be useful here)

(For the sake of completion and future reference).  You could also try to create a small batch script on windows and shell script on Linux. It is possible to detect the installation area from both.

bat -  see %~dp0%   - [Directory navigation in command prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059576/directory-navigation-in-command-prompts).
bash - [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! wordlist.xml should indeed be modifiable by the user, and I'd rather not make them put the file in a certain location, just like I really want to avoid making use of operating system specific functions. I'm surprised this seems to be such a tricky issue :/

Comment: Why not allow the user to select the location of file once?

Answer (score 0):

I would have kept a System Property for the file and keep the path of `dist` by default. In case file is present in `data` which is Development environment the application would pick it up otherwise it will always go to pick up file for `dist`.

You can do like:

```
// This would pick up system property if set otherwise default value provided.
String filePath = (String) System.getProperty("VOCAB_FILE_PATH","<<path with dist>>"); 
public File vocabFile = new File(filePath);
```

**In you NetBeans environment just set a system property `VOCAB_FILE_PATH` with path mentioned as `data`.**